# XMLHttpRequest is sending content-type as HTML instead of json

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, google-chrome, firefox

XMLHttpRequest is sending `content-type` as `HTML` instead of `json` and shows a 404 error, however, after few seconds (tested with 15 seconds) it starts working as expected and starts sending the data with json content-type.
This happens in both Firefox as well as in Chrome.

However, this works while I send the same request by `replay XHR` or `edit and replay` in chrome or firefox respectively.

here are my codes.
Getting XMLHTTPRequest Object

```
        //Browser Support Code
        function ajaxobj() {
            var ajaxRequest;

            // The variable that makes Ajax possible!
            try {
                // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
                ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            catch (e) {
                // Internet Explorer Browsers
                try {
                    ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                }
                catch (e) {
                    try {
                        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                    catch (e) {
                        // Something went wrong
                        //alert("Your browser broke!");
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            return ajaxRequest;

        }
```

Function to send the data to the server.

```
        var serverData = "localhost";
        // A function to send the JSON data to the server
        function ajaxInit(urlId, query) {
            // getting and setting the ajaxRequest object
            var ajaxRequest = ajaxobj();
            ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (ajaxRequest.readyState == 4) {
                    if (ajaxRequest.status == 200) {
                        console.log("Response got from server : ",ajaxRequest.responseText);
                        try{
                            var mainResponse = JSON.parse(ajaxRequest.responseText);
                            ajaxResponse(mainResponse);
                        }
                        catch(e){
                            console.log("There has been an error on the server. Please try again later!!!")
                        }


                    }
                    else
                        errorCallback(ajaxRequest.status);
                }
            }

            var serverData = {};
            serverData.data = [];
            // settin the url ID as the server ID in the data
            query.type = urlId;
            serverData.data.push(query);

            ajaxRequest.open("POST", serverPage, true);
            ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
            ajaxRequest.send(JSON.stringify(serverData));
            //console.log(JSON.stringify(serverData));
        }
```

Sending the data to the server.

```
// sending on page load  
// didnt worked 404 error  
ajaxInit("index", formData);
// sending after 3 seconds. 
// didn't worked 404 error
setTimeout(() => {
    ajaxInit("index", formData); 
},3000);
// sending after 15 seconds. 
// luckily this workd
setTimeout(() => {
    ajaxInit("index", formData); 
},15000);
```